# Linq pass an Indexer as IEnumerable.Select selector

Tags: c#, linq, indexer

Is there a syntax that allows passing an indexer as `Select(Func<T,TResult> selector)` selector? For example is there a shorthand (i.e. without 'arrow') for following code using an indexer:

```
// full version using indexer
collection.Select(key => dictionary[key]);
```

in the same way as there is for any other member functions? e.g.:

```
// full
collection.Select(key => dictionary.ContainsKey(key));
// shorthand
collection.Select(dictionary.ContainsKey);
```

none of following seems to work:

```
// shorthand attempts with invalid syntax
collection.Select(dictionary.[]);
collection.Select(dictionary[]);
```

indexers are just methods after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly write the "method group" for an indexer, but you can write an extension method on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and use use the method group of that:

```
public static TValue Get<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key) => dict[key];
```

Now you can use `someDict.Get` in your lambda.